# Magento 2- Redirect customer to home page after customer session expires instead login page?

Tags: magento2, session

i want to redirect the customer to the home page after session get expired. Right now it get redirected to the login page. How can i achieve it. Any  help welcome.

Comment: It doesn't work customer-data.js simple clear all storage and that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding

File: `\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\Session.php`

Line Around : 494

```
    $this->response->setRedirect(
        $this->_createUrl()->getUrl(\Magento\Customer\Model\Url::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN, $arguments)
    );
```

You just need change to the constant `\Magento\Customer\Model\Url::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN`